# Splitting up Values in the same cell in excel

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Example]

Can anyone help with this? I want to create 3 new columns from the data pulled in the fifth column that separates the numbers from the dashes. So for cell containing "54-9-24", I need 3 new cells with 54, then 9, then 24.

NA

Comment: Data -> Data Tools -> Text to Columns

Comment: Or, `TEXTSPLIT()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or as follows:

For the leftmost number:

```
=left(F2,find("-",F2,1)-1)*1
```

For the middle number:

```
=MID(F2,FIND("-",F2,1)+1,(FIND("-",F2,FIND("-",F2,1)+1))-FIND("-",F2,1)-1)*1
```

For the last number:

```
RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-FIND("-",F2,FIND("-",F2,1)+1))*1
```

The *1 at the end makes sure the result is entered as a number, not text.