# How to apply number or date format to columns after TEXTSPLIT in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays, cell-formatting

I use `TEXTSPLIT` to cut text composed of multiple parts, like for example: the country, the date and the value:

**"USA-01/01/2023-1000"**

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-")
```

Unfortunately, the result is a spill formula (dynamic array) where the date and the value are "text" (which is normal after a text function). This poses a big problem if I want to SORT, because the sorting is applied as TEXT, not as date.

**Is there a way to have the date and number columns recognized as number, without having to enumerate each column to apply the format?**

*My current solution*:

For now I use let to name the textsplit part and I use choosecols for each column and multiply by 1 the number ones... before using SORT:

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(a,1),CHOOSECOLS(a,2)*1,CHOOSECOLS(a,3)*1))
```

But this seems overcomplicated... especially when the equivalent SPLIT array formula in GoogleSheet applies immediately the correct dates and number format to each part.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to avoid enumerating the columns with choosecols

Comment: And using TEXT, the result is still "text" not a date, which means that sorting on this column will be incorrect for dates.

Comment: You could use: `=LET(d,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),IFERROR(d+0,d))` but you'll have manually apply any number/date formatting to the relevant cells.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thank you for the editing of the post. I will try to follow these guidelines in the future.

Comment: Please @Rory can you post it as an anwser so that I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: Or you could check this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76573858/4961700

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
=LET(d,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),IFERROR(d+0,d))
```

but you'll have to manually apply any number/date formatting to the relevant cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, I credited you in my tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeQnMxxZL0U (delete this comment when seen).